# How to add a class to body tag based on the section which is in viewport

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hey I am new in jquery and i am stuck, I have html like this

```html
<section id="help">Help</section>
<section id="touch">Touch</section>
<section id="payment">Payment</section>
<section id="toys">Toys</section>
```

So now if touch section is in viewport then add class to body (body class name is "**touch-active**")

and i am trying this code but it is not working for me:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if (jQuery('section').is(':visible')){
         jQuery('body').addClass(.attr('id + active'));;
    }
 });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `.addClass(.attr('id + active'));;` looks like a copy paste error, is that your actual code or a mistake while editing the question?

Comment: Yes it was mine mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use an IntersectionObserver to detect when an element comes in to view. From there you can remove all classes from the `body` and replace it with a new class based on the visible `section`. Try this:

```js
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('section')
var obsOptions = {
  root: null, // measure against the viewport
  threshold: .5 // how much of the element should be visible before handler is triggered
}

let handler = (entries, opts) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > opts.thresholds[0]) {
      document.body.classList.remove(...document.body.classList);
      document.body.classList.add(entry.target.id + '-active');
    }
  })
}

targets.forEach(el => {
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler, obsOptions);
  observer.observe(el);
})
```

```css
section {
  height: 250px;
}

body.help-active { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
body.touch-active { background-color: #DDDDDD; }
body.payment-active { background-color: #BBBBBB; }
body.toys-active { background-color: #999999; }
```

```html
<section id="help">Help</section>
<section id="touch">Touch</section>
<section id="payment">Payment</section>
<section id="toys">Toys</section>
```

Comment: Working fine for me. You saved my day :)

Comment: Using `document.body.classList.remove(...document.body.classList);` it is remove other class as well from body. How can i stop them?

Comment: I used that logic as it removes all classes from the body, as I assumed you couldn't guarantee the classnames used at runtime. If you know the classnames that you want to remove in advance you can `remove()` them directly by name. Alternatively, you can remove all the classes (including the dynamic ones) and add back those you *have* to keep on the body.

Comment: Problem is that i am use wordpress and wordpress plugin is added some classes in pages so thats why i am not assuming which class added or not. I much appreciate If you provide me quick solution.